# What pitch notation terms are used in Britain?

Tags: terminology

Is it Scientific pitch notation or Helmholtz pitch notation or something else entirely?

I'm writing a not-so-short story set in a conservatory, and I'm a bit over my head with terminology, and it doesn't help that all of my knowledge in this area is either in my native language or from Glee, which is American, when I'd like to keep the whole of my story in British English.

So, if a character asks his student to reach a certain note, would he ask to sing a F6 or three-line F or…?

Comment: Do you mean a Conservatoire? A conservatory in Britain is a room with lots of glass, and often a glass roof.

Comment: [An F6 is out of range for a typical soprano, let alone a student](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soprano#Voice_type). If you want to be really accurate that is much more important then the notation system you want to talk about.

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Conservatoire vs. Conservatory was one of the things I was unsure about.

Comment: @Dom It isn't for a coloratura soprano, and it was just an example.

Comment: @Kaworu the "big three" music schools in the UK are not usually called "conservatoires". They are the Royal Academy of Music and the Royal College of Music, both in London, and the Royal Northern College of Music in Manchester. They are often referred to simply by their initials, RAM, RCM, and RNCM. Other institutions are typically called "School", "Academy", "College," or "Department of Music" at a university.

Comment: @Dom somebody should have told Mozart that, before he wrote "The Magic Flute" ;) Actually, I've heard a mezzo (who was a music college student at the time) hit that top F right in the middle "just for fun" at the end of Mozart's "Exultate, Jubilate".

Comment: @alephzero Thanks for the explanation (really, it's not sarcastic), but the story isn't set in Britain, I'm just sticking to British English and terms because I want to untangle the British-American mess that my English has become, and I'd like to stay on the British side for the time being. Still, School/Academy/College are useful, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's at the upper range of the student's voice, the teacher will just use the word "high."  For example, "the high C" or "the high F" or whatever.

Comment: Absolutely. If the OP is just looking for the kind of language that would be used in speech, this is spot on. A teacher and pupil talking about a note wouldn't use anything complicated - that would sound contrived in a story.

Comment: Presumably the teacher is referring to a passage in a piece or etude, so perhaps  "the high-C in the first development" , for example.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Ha ha!  I can't imagine singers being that aware of music theory stuff!

Comment: @aparente001  Not all singers are sopranos  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - My impression is that C would probably work if the student is a tenor.  Can you suggest notes for the others, in case the author has something else in mind?

Comment: @aparente001I don't actually. :) There's just one soprano girl I'm going to follow more or less closely studies-wise, the others are pianists and strings.

Comment: It doesn't even answer the question "What pitch notation terms are used in Britain"!